# Add shortcode with open close function

Tags: shortcode

I have a website with a lot of

```
[mybutton]click here[/mybutton]
```

or

```
[mybutton]click there[/mybutton]
```

in editor. 
I need to add a function to create a href from this shortcodes. Closing of shortcode is a problem for me. How can i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the functionality of a shortcode you must first `remove_shortcode( 'shortcode_name' );` where shortcode name is the name of the shortcode. Add the shortcode back with your NEW function.

A simple example to follow what you might be needing:

```
    remove_shortcode( 'mybutton' );
    add_shortcode( 'mybutton', 'my_shortcode_function' );

    my_shortcode_function( $atts, $content = "" ) {
        return '<a href="http://example.com">' . $content . '</a>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a short code not HTML you can put any Attribute there, if you want that function got to your page builder and insert a text editor and to html editor and create a button so you can put any attribute you want in it.

Comment: I have 500 pages with this kind of shortcodes so I would like to use function than changing it manually

Comment: what do you want your function to do ?

Comment: [mybutton] to <a href="#">
[/mybutton] to </a>

Comment: No that will not work, the button will not show if you do that... try ```<a href="#">[mybutton]click there[/mybutton]</a>``` I hope it works